# session resumption using session ids in mqtt

Tags: session, openssl, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have wrote the paho-client programs( 1-publisher ,1-subscriber) using C.   And I am able to transmit the data through mosquitto broker with TLSv2.   Now i want to enable session resumption using session ID.

What changes are to be done in my mosquitto broker configuration file and in my client C programs...

Openssl says server needs to generate session ids, which means mosquitto in this context. However, `mosquitto.conf` has no option to setup a cache (storing session ids). I have traced the packets through Wireshark , packets are encrypted, but every time a new session ticket is sent. I just want to  optimize the handshake by using session resumption(preferably using session IDs or session tickets).

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed on the mosquitto dev mailing list back in August 2017 [here](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/mosquitto-dev/msg01605.html).

The implication is that there is noting to configure on the broker side, mosquitto will cache session ids for 300 seconds.

As for the client side it looks like there was no built in support for this and you will need to look at using `SSL_set_session()` to apply a save session to the socket and `SSL_CTX_sess_set_new_cb()` to save the session for reuse.

Comment: I have already went through the dev mailing list , it is of not much use. And it deals with session tickets ,no information is given about session IDs. For client side , i have used **SSL_set_session()** & referred this link https://nachtimwald.com/2014/10/06/client-side-session-cache-in-openssl/ which does the session resumption with sockets.  Since MQTT(mosquitto) does not deal with sockets , I am not able to apply the information present in the link into my paho-client programs..

Comment: The best place to follow up will be the mailing list

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1094988/ .Done this way back, no replies over there from 1831 viewers !

Comment: Post to the dev mailing list not the forum, much more likely to get a response. Also that post is all on one line so I doubt it actually got read that many times